# Is it "bad" to try and learn southern American English?

Tags: american-english, speech, north-american-english, southern-white-vernacular-english

I have always been really interested in south American life style, culture, and specially language, a while back, I asked a professional American English teacher, about if it was OK to try and learn southern English, his statement could be summed up into a big NO. And he was acting like it was not ok at all to learn it.

Now what do you guys think? And if you think it is ok, or if it is not give me the reasons why it is or isn't alright to learn southern English as a foreign learner from Iran who is fascinated with southern American English.

Also I would be more than thankful if you could direct me towards some online sources where I could learn southern English. Thank you.

Comment: I'd start with "Achy, Breaky Heart"

Comment: Are you hoping to mimic the ***phonology*** (accent), the ***lexis*** (vocabulary and idioms), or ***grammar*** (syntax and morphology) peculiar to the dialects of the American South? Did you have a particular region in mind like *Texan English* or *Appalachian English*? Do you want an urban dialect or a rural one? Were you aiming to learn *Southern White Vernacular English* or *African American Vernacular English*? Have you considered the cognitive dissonance many would experience upon seeing an Asian face yet nonetheless hearing a white dialect or a black dialect coming out of that speaker?

Comment: @tchrist well, to be honest I speak US American accent with almost not Iranian accent, people from the US sometimes find it hard to believe that I am from Iran. honestly trying to 'mimic' an accent is something that would always endup sounding out of place and weird so I am only trying to learn what I can, would never really approach it in a 'mimic' style. I just want to understand, and if I endup talking to a sweet southerner I want to be somewhat familiar.

Comment: @tchrist the fact is that I enjoy the way southern English sounds very much, also I like the expressions, they sound like cookies for the ears, like "butter my butt and call me a biscuit' who would not fall in love with that?

Comment: Most English language learners have enough trouble just getting a command of English itself down that they don't bother with the peculiarities of regional dialects unless they're actually living there. But it sounds like you're beyond that stage. I've definitely heard many Iranians speak English with almost no accent spilling over from Farsi, but I also have several first-generation Iranian-American friends whose parents I've met. My experience is that if you aren't used to non-rhotic dialects, that can be the hardest to figure out.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you're looking for "folksy idioms". I don't know that those can be pre-learned outside an immersion environment, or at least an environment where you come into active contact with them.

Comment: @tchrist yes, a thousand times yes, FINALLY someone who got it, exactly, I am looking for expressions, idioms, slang terms, and a tinsy bit of that sweet accent. Are you saying that there is NO way I could learn some of that besides immersion, cause as much as I would love to deep dive into such an immersion environment, I can not afford such opportunity really.

Comment: @tchrist I mean when I hear some southern slang or accent in a movie this whole thirst begins again

Comment: If you use a regional dialect and you are a non-native speaker it can sound very humorous and be a distraction if you are attempting to communicate with native speakers. I've seen people burst out laughing upon hearing non-native speakers saying things ilke "ain't" and "y'all."

Comment: @aris I know exactly what you mean, and that is why I don't like the idea of 'mimic'-ing the accent, but occasional clearly deliberate attempts that would cause a few laughs and lift up the spirits would not hurt any one I suppose.

Comment: Sometimes it amuses me, and _really annoys_ my wife, if I pretend to be one of the characters from _Deputy Dawg_. Muskie, mostly. I will incorporate "Butter my butt and call me a biscuit, Dep'ty Dawg!" into my collection of sayings.

Comment: @JackBixuis - just follow your instinct.

Comment: Southern American English is not a prestigious dialect in the U.S. There are lots of Southerners who have tried very hard to get rid of their accents. So if you're not actually in the South, it might not be a good idea to use it.

Comment: It is never bad to try and learn a language. Any language. Godspeed. Not sure why you even ask total strangers on the Internet for their opinion. You want to give it a try, give it a try. Start today.

Comment: I can't think of a way to learn Southern AE besides immersion. Dictionaries and recordings preserve some mannerisms, but you need practice in order to master appropriate usage in context. (Gender, social status, ethnicity - the effects of those on speech are subtle but present.) As a born Southerner, I know first and second generation immigrants who code switch very effectively, and I know several-generation native speakers who would only be betrayed by occasional word choice. Regardless, best of luck, and take care now, y'hear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts for you

- All-in-all, English is not a very dialectical language. Regional variation between standard Englishes are relatively modest. Tons of speakers speak only in a standard dialect. It is very common for native speakers to speak only a standard dialect.
- White Southern English pronunciation varies a lot by region, and is very seldom portrayed accurately in TV shows or movies. https://thisamericanlife.org/138/the-real-thing/act-three-0 is a fun rant on Hollywood getting Southern accents wrong.

  Many, *many* speakers (especially non-rural or more-educated speakers) in the South have very standard accents that are hard to distinguish from Americans in other parts of the country.
- To continue the point above, it's important to understand that TV and movies do not match reality. While southern white English speakers are known for their colorful expressions, a stock southern character in a film is likely to have more plentiful, more exotic, and more over-the-top ones than real speakers one will meet.

  If you do really want to learn some colorful southern expressions, consider sticking to ones whose meanings are self-explanatory, or not only might they seem out-of-place, but also simply not be understood. **As mad as a wet hen** explains itself--even with limited poultry knowledge, I can surmise that a wet hen must be very mad. **He's been hung out to dry** is a lot less clear to people who don't know the expression. This is especially key, since any resources you find listing expressions might list some that do not have any real use in the wild.
- There is something about colorful expressions where it is usually easy to notice if they do not come naturally to a speaker. This can be distracting at times, but is not necessarily a problem. It's normal enough for people to use colorful expressions in a way that is clearly more distant.

Comment: As much as I loved the other comments and posts and answers I have to choose this one as the answer as it was more to the point and really informative, thank you for that. everyone else's comments were also really amazing and got the juices flowing really interesting and sweet, the southern kind of sweet. yooohoooo! Love you guys!

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine why it would not be okay for you to learn it. After all, it's okay for Southern US Americans to learn it, and it's not like Southern US Americans are better than Iranians.

In particular, if you plan on *living* in the Southern US, there's nothing wrong with trying to fit in.

Comment: As logically accurate as you may be and you totally are, in my opinion, there, I guess, is a lot of dispute around the subject of trying to 'fit in', if it happens naturally and in an acceptable way then it is fine and appreciated, but if the subject who is trying to fit in, does not really know how to do it, this can on many occasions endup in an awkwardness of a lifetime, and haunt the subject their whole life. I think 'trying to fit in' needs to happen in somewhat of a controlled manner, with consideration for cultural rules and etiquette. I don't know! I may be wrong!

Comment: Note that in most of the South, you do not have to speak a Southern dialect to *fit in*. There are tons of native southerners who speak only standard American English in a fairly neutral American accent. (There are identifiable markers, but they are so minor many lay people do not pick up on them.)

Comment: "but if the subject who is trying to fit in, does not really know how to do it, this can on many occasions endup in an awkwardness of a lifetime," - there is a charming young Polish woman who works in my office, and I think maybe she has begun to assimilate (she is married to a Brit). When she says 'bloody 'ell!' it is very charming, believe me.